# Setting SelectedValue in a Telerik DropDownList in a RadGrid

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to set the SelectedValue of a RadDropDownList in the EditTemplate of my RadGrid.  The DataItemBound event appears to be throwing an error on compilation.

ASP.NET

```
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="givenAnswer" HeaderText="givenAnswer" UniqueName="givenAnswer">
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "givenAnswer") %>
                </ItemTemplate> 
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="ddlGivenAnswer" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ddlGivenAnswer_DataBound">
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes" />
                            <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="No" Value="No" />
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

C#

```
        protected void ddlGivenAnswer_DataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Item.IsInEditMode))
        {
            GridEditFormItem item = (GridEditFormItem)e.Item;
            RadDropDownList ddl = (RadDropDownList)item.FindControl("ddlgivenAnswer");
            ddl.SelectedValue = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "givenAnswer").ToString();
        }
    }
```

Error

```
CS0123: No overload for 'ddlGivenAnswer_DataBound' matches delegate 'DropDownListItemEventHandler'
```

This error is being throw on the telerik:RadDropDownList open tag line in ASP.NET.  What am I missing here?

Comment: The idea of changing the Value of the selected Item make you eligeable for a voting machine dev job !

Answer (score 0):

## Main Edit:

#### Error `CS0123`:

First typing `CS0123` in Google show me that you were using wrong parameter for your event. Probably a copypast fail. Delete the even in the aspx and ask to intelisense to create a new one. Or copypast this one.

> ```
> protected void ddlGivenAnswer_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.DropDownListItemEventArgs e)
> ```

#### ItemDataBound:

ItemDataBound occure when a data is bound in a control.

I'am pretty sure that inline declaration are not going to fire this event.

#### Minor Misconception:

Why would someone change the Value of a selected element dynamically?
It's like changing the value of a vote without changing the vote him self or the name on the vote.

What you want is to check the rigth item.
To check Waldo in the drop down list :

```
ddlGivenAnswer.FindItemByValue("Waldo").Selected = true;
```

To check the right Item:

```
ddlGivenAnswer.FindItemByValue( 
                                DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "givenAnswer").ToString()
                               ).Selected = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I have changed the line to this...

ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.FindItemByValue((string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "givenAnswer").ToString()).Index;

However, that doesn't fix the error.

Comment: If you put no code in ddlGivenAnswer_DataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e) is the  error still there ?